# Windows 10 and network drive

Tags: windows-10

as you can see in the image the problem is:
when I'm browsing a network folder with an external program (in this case "unloker"), the connected network drives aren't available. I have this problem with lots of program.

[image]

Someone could help me? I've already tried to re-connect drives and reboot.
This is a clean installation of windows 10, i've tried with three other pc and the problem is the same.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this closed as (off-topic). Mapped network drives and Windows are part of many automation build setups that directly involve software development..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the effect of the User Account control (UAC) which was added in Windows Vista in 2006. [When you map drives at logon, they are mapped with the filtered token (standard rights). When you now run an application elevated (with full admin token) it can't see the mapped drives of the normal permissions.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

> When network shares are mapped, they are linked to the current logon
>   session for the current process access token. This means that if a
>   user uses the command prompt (cmd.exe) together with the filtered
>   access token to map a network share, the network share is not mapped
>   for processes that run with the full administrator access token.

To allow admin programs to see the normal mapped drives, enable the setting `EnableLinkedConnections`

> Click Start, type **regedit** in the Start programs and files box, and
>   then press ENTER.
>
> Locate and then right-click the registry subkey
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**.
>
> Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>
> Type **EnableLinkedConnections**, and then press `ENTER`.
>
> Right-click EnableLinkedConnections, and then click Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>
> Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Now everything works for you as expected.

Comment: I don't know why people unlike my problem, but I think that it is a good question and was very hard to solve. Your solution works and you just saved my life! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: such (non programkming related) questions should asked on superuser.com, that's why you got the down votes. I voted to migrate the question so superuser.com

Comment: ok, can I migrate the question? I didn't know it, sorry. Where can I vote to migrate question?

Comment: you can't migrate it. This requires some prestige until you can do it.

Comment: I had the same problem and it helped me as well. I think when you're a programmer and reach this kind of problem, until you figure out what is the solution, you just can't know whether this is *programming related*, because you don't know what is causing the problem (bad code? language known bug?). If people downvote, it's because they already know what is the problem and possible causes, so why don't they share their knowledge and put the OP in the right way just like you did, along with closing for being off-topic?

Comment: @Alisson a lot of people are very strange when it comes to voting. ignore it. I was also the only user who voted to migrate it. all 4 other simply voted to close the question. this is also a totally strange behavior here.

Comment: [Registry Patch File](https://gist.github.com/druciferre/f3b9fce49ee609651929ce26008f5fe0) for anyone who doesn't want to do this manually. Just right click on Raw button and click Save Link As.

Comment: Add a sheduled task at user logon to create the drives. One as a normal users and 1 task with elevated rights! So all programs that you run with elevated privs will now find the network drives to.

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva Well, bad code or known bug in some language would only make sense if the question would actually contain some code. If the asker had developed some program themselves and it would fail to connect to the network drive, it would be a different story. That would be programming-related. But the question is just about Windows, there is no code (or programming-related tool) involved in the question. It's not depending on the solution whether the question is programming-related or not.

Comment: @CherryDT you're right, I was more intrigued by the fact only one person suggested to migrate to the right place (e.g. superuser) and other people just voted to close as off-topic. This kind of behavior from SO veterans explains why so many people think SO is toxic, at the same time I ask myself if that's also the reason why it's a successful platform.

Comment: @CherryDT btw I still wonder if SO could get even better if people just were nicer while following the rules. I know people flagging are volunteers, but if they don't have time to help a new user (who put quite some effort making a good quality question) like guiding them to the right forum, why not just skip to the next question instead? Bear with me, this is just me sharing thoughts and wondering about people behavior, I like SO as a platform nonetheless and put my small share of effort into helping people.