# Why is my mapped network drive not appearing in Network Locations?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, process.start

I'm using Windows 10. Here is my code to map the network drive.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "use Z: " + dPath; //dPath has escaped characters
p.Start();
```

What I was trying to do was trying to run the command `net.exe use Z: DPATH` as administrator but the Z drive does not appear in File Explorer but when I run the exact same command using cmd with Admin rights, the Z drive appears correctly.

---

**Proof of mapped drive**

My Network drive is mapped as evidenced below (Encountered this error when trying to re-map it manually) just that it wasn't appearing under Network Locations in File Explorer > This PC.

[image: attemptingToMap]

Comment: What user is the network drive mapped to? What user is your code running under? Do they match? Your code is likely running under a different user than your logged in as. So it will have a different view of the mapped drives

Comment: @Liam pardon me but how do I identify that? I only have one user on my computer.

Comment: I would suggest you don't. Even basic versions of windows have multiple users. You need to give context as to **how** and **where** the C# code you've included is being run? Is this a website, windows app, powershell?

Comment: @Liam a windows app with win forms for use on windows desktops.

Comment: Are you running the exe as administrator?

Comment: its not showing because you do a runas - its not running in the same session you're in

Comment: @Liam yes, I'm running it with admin rights.

Comment: @BugFinder Ok, so I removed the `p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` line and it appeared briefly with an X sign... but then disappeared after I refreshed the File Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by UAC (User Account Control). When logging on to Windows as an admin, [there are two sessions created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238581/windows-10-and-network-drive). One with admin rights and one without. When you map the drives programmatically, you are doing it with the session with admin rights.

However, when you use File Explorer to view the Network Locations, you are using standard rights. For mapped drives, the admin and standard rights are not shared. Hence, the admin is not able to view the mapped drive eventhough it was created with admin rights.

**Solution 1**

> Click Start, type regedit in the Start programs and files box, and
> then press ENTER.
>
> Locate and then right-click the registry subkey
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System.
>
> Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>
> Type EnableLinkedConnections, and then press ENTER.
>
> Right-click EnableLinkedConnections, and then click Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>
> Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

**Solution 2**

[Run File Explorer as administrator](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/144776-unable-to-open-an-elevated-windows-explorer-window/)

> When making a right click on the Explorer and select "Run as
> administrator" it doesn't start the Windows Explorer with admin
> rights. The Windows Vista/7/8/10 Explorer includes a special function to
> block such requests.
>
> To disable it, start regedit.exe and go to the following key:
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}
>
> make a right click on Permissions and set your user as owner of the key and
> give your current user writing permissions.
>
> Next, delete or rename the value RunAs. Now the Elevated-Unelevated
> Explorer Factory is disabled and you can start the Explorer with admin
> rights.

**Solution 3**

If the above can't work, [disable your UAC (User Account Control)](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-uac-in-windows-10/) by going into User Account Control Settings and moving the slider to **Never notify**

Also, if you have Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate version of windows installed, you need to look into a program in Administrative tools called **Local Security Policy** and disable all the policies related to UAC in **Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options** (Located in the bottom 15 policies of the list)

Answer (score 2):

It helped me restarting explorer.exe with admin rights via Task Manager.