# Access denied to network printer in PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print to a network printer from code, but the network printer status in the print dialog box says `Access denied, unable to connect` and the print button is disabled. But I can print to that printer just fine if I print from another application. And, if I select Print to PDF from the print dialog, that also works fine. I just can't print to the network printer. Am i having some kind of permissions issue?

```
if (File.Exists(previewDocument))
    File.Delete(previewDocument);

PrintDialog printD = new PrintDialog();
printD.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
printD.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

if (printD.ShowDialog() ?? false)
{
    XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(previewDocument, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
    xpsWriter.Write(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)messageFlow).DocumentPaginator);

    FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    printD.PrintDocument(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator, "Hello!");
}
```

Comment: You may well check the context on which your application trying to run. You may impersonate the application context if you application run under a privilege which doesn't allow to print.

Comment: Try to run your application as administrator.

Comment: Are you getting this error from a build of the program or from Debug?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code fragment after instantiating your print dialogue to find your shared network printer and print to it

```
printD.PrintQueue = New PrintQueue(New PrintServer(@"\\computer server name"), "the exact name of your network printer")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I cannot have a static printer. Every user have a different network printer.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you cannot have static printer. In what scenario does every user have a different network printer. 

If such is the case then you need wmi query to list the network printer for the logged on user and then select that in your wpf application.

Follow this

 https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2007/07/17/how-can-i-list-the-network-printers-for-the-logged-on-user/

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment yet but I wanted to share my thought regarding your problem.

I have had problem getting access to Network drives from my applications.
Even when running as Admin. I'm thinking printers are accessed in a similar way.

My problem was with User Account control (UAC).

Try setting a register according to this: [Windows 10 and network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238581/windows-10-and-network-drive)