# how to use local file acces rights while running powershell as administrator

Tags: powershell, admin, local, restriction

So, I have an admin account to install programs, but with that admin account, I do not have access to a network location, which I can access as local user.

I am building scripts that installs multiple programs and afterwards copies a bunch of config files from a network location to a local machine. Some items require admin rights to be copied.

Ideally I want to execute a script as administrator, but use the local user rights to access the config files on the network location within the same script.

I have searched google for hours now, but I still do not have a solution. Someone an idea on how to accomplish this? asking for the missing access rights, is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 and network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238581/windows-10-and-network-drive)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have read the article, but I do not insert drive names.in my code. I directly refer to network share such as --> \\SERVERNAME\

Comment: Hi Michel  you can make a networkshare PSdrive in your powershell with admin credentials ...

Comment: Thanks, but will this still work, when the admin account itself does not have access to the networkshare?

Comment: you can give a diferance accont to that share in your script

Comment: I will search the internet again on how to accomplish this, but if you would have that answer as well, that would be perfect. I really appreciate your prompt responses yesterday. Very helpful