# Why Inno Setup installer doesn't handle correctly network drive?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, mapped-drive

When I use an Inno Setup installer in Windows 10, I can't select files from a network drive. For example, in the following picture, I can't access the `S:` drive and browse its content:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this problem seems related to the User Account Control (UAC) as explained in this post : [Windows 10 and network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238581/windows-10-and-network-drive/33241079#33241079).
Thanks to @StayOnTarget for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup FAQ includes topic
[Mapped drives aren't showing up on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page, or cannot be browsed into](https://jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#missingmappeddrives):

> Your installation requires administrative privileges and is running elevated:
>
> Mapped drives are not available (by default) to any elevated application. This was introduced in Windows Vista.
>
> There is an [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee844140(v=ws.10)) to make them available for same user elevation, but this won't help the situation when run from a LUA where the user changes.

Also, see [Windows 10 and network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33238581/850848)